# SQL Server BCP only one row inserted?

Tags: csv, bcp, eol, linefeed

I'm using an FMT file to BCP a csv file into a an SQL Server Box - everything is fine, but only the first row of the 5 line file is getting inserted.

I think it is the line feed settings for the terminator of the final column - but how do I view and edit the line feeds in the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a free editor which you can use to view (View / Show Symbol / Show End of Line) and edit (Edit / EOL Conversion / Windows Format) the end of lines.